# Privacy policy for adMob

Tags: admob, adsense, privacy-policy

I have a game in google play that I published more than a year ago. I was using AdMob ads and its mediation. Till May 2018 ads are working properly. But after AdMob updated its privacy policy I couldn't get any ads at all. So I did some research and found that I need to add some privacy policy to my game. I added it in app's data in google play console and mentioned in it that I'm using AdMob and other third party service and added some details. But after this ads are not appear.

Do I need to add popup and button in game for player to accept privacy policy? And how can I connect to AdMob maybe they disable my account?

Answer (score 0):

AdMob generally serves personalized ads so you may need to get user consent under GDPR for this:

[image]

[Google Developer Policy Center](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/user-data/) is clear what you need to have in your Privacy Policy:

> You must be transparent in how you handle user data (e.g., information collected from or about a user, including device information). That means disclosing the collection, use, and sharing of the data, and limiting the use of the data to the purposes disclosed, and the consent provided by the user.

Comment: Please confirm:
 as I understand I NEED to have popup in my app?